# MD5 Hash Brute Force java

Tags: md5

I am having some trouble creating a brute force java code for a class assignment. The professor is not much help I was hoping someone could lend me a hand or give some tips. The professor supplied two methods `md5_bytes` and `mini_md5_bytes`. The mini bytes is used to decode 24 bits instead of the full hash. I have tried to go about it on my own and I have hit a wall. The random string generator was my attempt at trying to use random strings to eventually find the hash for the preselected word s.  I appreciate the help.

```
public class BruteForce {
static int num_bytes=24;
static String rand = "";
static String s = "aefbcefacefeacaecefc";
static byte[] random = null;
static byte[] md = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    md = mini_md5_bytes(s, num_bytes);
    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(rand)){
        System.out.println(rand);
    }
    else{
        rand = brute(md, s);
    }

}




public static byte[] mini_md5_bytes(String s, int num_bytes){

    byte[] md = md5_bytes(s);

    return Arrays.copyOf(md,num_bytes);

}
public static byte[] md5_bytes(String s){

     MessageDigest md;
     try {
         md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
         md.update(s.getBytes());
         return md.digest();
     } catch( java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
         return null;
     }
 }
public static String brute(byte[] md, String s) throws Exception{
    while(!s.equalsIgnoreCase(rand)){
        rand =  RandomStringGenerator.generateRandomString(20,RandomStringGenerator.Mode.ALPHA);
        byte[] random = mini_md5_bytes(rand, num_bytes);
            if((Arrays.equals(random, md))){
                rand = s;
                return rand;
            }               
    }
    return null;

   }


 }
```

Comment: if you want to use brute force, it's better to code for all values, not using a random generator.

Comment: What exactly is your trouble? That the code takes forever to run? Of course it does - you're trying to brute force a hash using random strings!

Comment: Im also not clear of the issue. Does it not work? Does it not finish?  You'll never complete with random strings, because you can never tell where you are/where you've been and you might end up trying the same one repeatedly. I'd recommend building an "attempted" list as you go.

Comment: So a count variable that increments? It just runs forever I even tried limiting the alphabet it uses. Is there a way I can eliminate a random string as I go to make it go faster or will it always just make a random

Answer (score 1):

Whilst MD5 is [no longer considered safe for crypto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security), that does not imply that MD5 is easy to brute force.

As others have suggested in comments, don't try random strings (especially because generation of random numbers is slow). [Brute force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) is about trying all combinations until a match is found.

Also, by reading your `mini_md5_bytes()` it seems that you don't want to find two strings with exactly the same MD5 hash, but just with the same MD5 "prefix".

If that's the case, then use a small number for `num_bytes`. Maybe start with 1 or 2 and then increase the number until your tool becomes too slow. By the way, note that you're using `num_bytes=24`, i.e. 192 bits, while [MD5 produces just 128 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5).

Also, why are you using `s.equalsIgnoreCase(rand)`? If you want to brute force an MD5 hash, then you should not care about the input string `s`. That string should not even be an input! If `s` were an input, you could use `rand = s` and you would be done. Your aim is to find a hash collision, not to find the original string.

This is the correct signature for your `brute()` function:

```
public static String brute(byte[] md) throws Exception
```

and this is the correct condition for the `while`-loop:

```
while(!Arrays.equals(random, md))
```

Comment: how would I go about trying all of the combinations? I have no idea how I would go about that. Some sort of loop I would assume?

Comment: @user4730535: first try with `"\x00"`, then `"\x01"`, ..., then `"\xff"`, then `"\x00\x00"`, ...